# MSacces datedifference function doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, datediff

I'm trying to use the DateDiff function in a query. It gives me an error when I use it though. I have MS-Access 2007. I try to use the DateDiff function in a query. I need to have the difference between these times in minutes.

This is want i'm trying to do:

```
 DateDiff('n',[timeregistered],[timeresolved])
```

And this is my error message:

```
You ommited an operand or operator, you entered an invalid character or comma, or you entered text without surrounding it in quotation marks.
```

Then the cursor goes to the first comma behind 'n'.
I've searched the microsoft site and the syntax appears to be correct.

Comment: Already tried it, didn't work. I tried removing the "" as well. But that did not work either.

Comment: Please show the FULL SQL Query. The error might not really be there.

Comment: MS-Access is a psuedo database.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `pseudo database`?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
DateDiff("n",[timeregistered],[timeresolved])
```

and/or:

```
DateDiff('n';[timeregistered];[timeresolved])
```